# "Is there any function in python like minifs and maxifs which compare two different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, data-analysis

I have two Data Frame, One contain unique customer_id & customer_name another data frame  containing there login in time stamp format. I want there first login date and last logout date

## The First Data set

[image: First Data Set]

## The Second Dataset

[image: Second Data Set]

It should create a new column first_login and last_login and assign the minimum start_time and maximum end_time to those unique customer_id

```
import pandas as pd
customer_unique = pd.read_excel('D:\\python\\customer.xlsx')
customer_time = pd.read_excel('D:\\python\\customer_login.xlsx')

new = customer_unique.loc[customer_unique.'customer_id' == customer_time.'customer_id','begin'] = customer_time('start_datetime').min()
```

## Desired Result

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
>>> df1
  Customer_ID Customer
0       EM065     Yash
1       EM077    Rahul
2       EM094   Rakesh
3       EM054    Dhanu
4       EM067    Ankit
5       EM023   Venkat
6       EM072   Ramesh
>>> df2
   Customer_ID          Start_Time            End_Time
0        EM065 2019-11-02 07:38:00 2019-11-02 09:26:00
1        EM077 2019-02-01 07:19:00 2019-02-01 11:05:00
2        EM065 2019-02-01 11:04:00 2019-02-01 11:44:00
3        EM072 2019-03-01 06:55:00 2019-03-01 08:55:00
4        EM067 2019-03-01 13:09:00 2019-03-01 14:21:00
5        EM067 2019-04-01 04:04:00 2019-04-01 06:18:00
6        EM067 2019-04-01 06:18:00 2019-04-01 06:18:00
7        EM094 2019-04-01 06:18:00 2019-04-01 06:18:00
8        EM023 2019-04-01 04:00:00 2019-04-01 06:19:00
9        EM077 2019-04-01 06:19:00 2019-04-01 06:19:00
10       EM065 2019-04-01 06:19:00 2019-04-01 06:19:00
11       EM094 2019-04-01 06:16:00 2019-04-01 10:11:00
12       EM065 2019-04-01 07:01:00 2019-04-01 11:53:00
13       EM077 2019-04-01 10:11:00 2019-04-01 10:11:00
14       EM054 2019-04-01 10:11:00 2019-04-01 10:11:00
15       EM065 2019-04-01 10:11:00 2019-04-01 10:11:00
16       EM065 2019-04-01 11:53:00 2019-04-01 11:53:00
17       EM072 2019-04-01 11:53:00 2019-04-01 11:53:00
18       EM072 2019-04-01 12:38:00 2019-04-01 14:54:00
19       EM077 2019-04-01 14:54:00 2019-04-01 14:54:00
20       EM067 2019-04-01 14:54:00 2019-04-01 14:54:00
21       EM094 2019-06-01 05:09:00 2019-06-01 07:53:00
22       EM072 2019-06-01 07:53:00 2019-06-01 07:53:00
23       EM077 2019-06-01 07:53:00 2019-06-01 07:53:00
24       EM065 2019-01-24 05:58:00 2019-01-24 05:58:00
25       EM077 2019-01-25 09:21:00 2019-01-25 12:26:00
26       EM067 2019-01-25 09:22:00 2019-01-25 12:27:00
27       EM072 2019-01-25 12:26:00 2019-01-25 15:48:00
28       EM067 2019-01-25 12:27:00 2019-01-25 15:50:00
29       EM094 2019-01-25 15:48:00 2019-01-25 15:48:00
30       EM077 2019-01-25 15:48:00 2019-01-25 15:48:00
31       EM067 2019-01-25 15:49:00 2019-01-25 16:14:00
32       EM094 2019-01-25 15:50:00 2019-01-25 16:15:00
33       EM077 2019-01-25 16:14:00 2019-01-25 16:14:00
34       EM065 2019-01-25 16:15:00 2019-01-25 16:15:00
35       EM065 2019-01-25 16:15:00 2019-01-25 16:15:00
36       EM072 2019-01-24 05:58:00 2019-01-24 05:58:00
37       EM067 2019-01-14 04:20:00 2019-01-14 06:02:00
38       EM065 2019-01-14 06:02:00 2019-01-14 06:02:00
39       EM065 2019-01-14 06:02:00 2019-01-14 06:02:00
40       EM054 2019-01-25 03:58:00 2019-01-25 06:52:00
41       EM023 2019-01-25 03:59:00 2019-01-25 06:53:00
42       EM077 2019-01-25 06:52:00 2019-01-28 03:39:00
43       EM094 2019-01-25 06:53:00 2019-01-28 03:42:00
44       EM065 2019-01-28 03:39:00 2019-01-28 03:39:00
45       EM067 2019-01-28 03:39:00 2019-01-28 03:39:00
46       EM077 2019-01-28 03:42:00 2019-01-28 03:42:00
47       EM065 2019-01-28 03:42:00 2019-01-28 03:42:00
48       EM094 2019-01-28 03:42:00 2019-01-28 03:42:00
49       EM077 2019-01-18 03:48:00 2019-01-18 03:48:00
50       EM065 2019-01-18 03:48:00 2019-01-18 03:48:00
```

we do:

```
res = df2.groupby('Customer_ID').agg({'Start_Time': min, 'End_Time': max})
res.insert(0, 'Customer', df1.set_index('Customer_ID'))
res.reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  Customer_ID Customer          Start_Time            End_Time
0       EM023   Venkat 2019-01-25 03:59:00 2019-04-01 06:19:00
1       EM054    Dhanu 2019-01-25 03:58:00 2019-04-01 10:11:00
2       EM065     Yash 2019-01-14 06:02:00 2019-11-02 09:26:00
3       EM067    Ankit 2019-01-14 04:20:00 2019-04-01 14:54:00
4       EM072   Ramesh 2019-01-24 05:58:00 2019-06-01 07:53:00
5       EM077    Rahul 2019-01-18 03:48:00 2019-06-01 07:53:00
6       EM094   Rakesh 2019-01-25 06:53:00 2019-06-01 07:53:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do

1. Group by Customer on second dataframe.
2. Find the first "Start" and the last "End" on the grouped dataframe
3. Left join the first dataframe with the result of step 2